# How to build a future proof cross site JS API in 2023?

Tags: cookies, cors, session-cookies, cross-site

So I was tasked with building a cross-site JS API which allows adding products to the shopping cart of a customer shop from their website on another domain.

Me (obviously being an idiot) did build a short proof of concept, tested that out and it worked fine. So I did build a full-fledged solution using CORS and a cross-site (Samesite=None) cookie.

Now doing QA on that, I realized, that while it works in Chrome and Edge, it doesn't reliably work in Firefox. Then I did find this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/third-party-cookies-firefox-tracking-protection

Bummer ... my whole solution seems like a dead end now, if Firefox disables third party cookies by default ...

Are Cross-Site-Cookies for functional use dead in 2023 for the sake of privacy protection? Is there any way around that? What solution should I have used instead?